# Ajax возвращает error со всей страницей

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Всем привет. Такая проблема: при выводе данных ajax запрос возвращает всю страницу, вместе с ответом. При создании пользователя и вводе всех полей происходит ajax запрос, который должен асинхронно подгружать все данные в бд и присылать ответ о успешном создании пользователя, но в ajax в error в консоль выводит всю страницу index.php вместе с ошибкой. Вот код:

ajax.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#feedback").submit(function(e) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var fd = new FormData();

    fd.append('send', 'send');
    fd.append('picture', $('#picture')[0].files[0]);
    fd.append('login', $('#login').val());
    fd.append('password', $('#password').val());
    fd.append('group', $('#group').val());
    fd.append('email', $('#email').val());
    fd.append('date', $('#date').val());

    $('#info').empty();

    $.ajax ({
        url: "application/controllers/ControllerUser.php",
        type: "POST",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        dataType: "json",
        data: fd,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            alert("success");
            //for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            //  $('#info').append("<li>" + data[i] + "</li>");
            //}
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert('Its error');
            console.log(xhr.responseText + '|\n' + status + '|\n' +error);
        }
    });
});
```

});

ControllerUser.php:

```
class ControllerUser extends Controller {

function __construct() {
    $this->model = new ModelUser();
    $this->view = new View();
    $this->db = Db::getInstance();
}

public function actionIndex() {

    $grouplist = $this->model->getAllRow('group');

    if(isset($_POST['send'])) {
        $data = array();
        $login = $this->db->escape($_POST['login']);
        $password = $this->db->escape($_POST['password']);
        $group = $this->db->escape($_POST['group']);
        $email = $this->db->escape($_POST['email']);
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $image = $_FILES['picture'];//картинка
        //var_dump($date);

        //Проверка логина на уникальность
        $res = $this->model->getData($login);
        $row = $this->db->fetch_assoc($res);
        $this->model->unique($row);

        //Корректность логина и эмейла
        $this->model->regex(ModelUser::LOGIN_PATTERN, $login, 'Некорректный логин');
        $this->model->regex(ModelUser::EMAIL_PATTERN, $email, 'Некорректный email');

        //Изображение абонента
        $path = 'images/';
        $explode = explode('.', $image['name']);
        $ext = array_pop($explode);

        //Проверка изображения
        $this->model->typeImg($ext, "Неподходящий тип картинки");
        $this->model->sizeImage($image, "Неподходящий размер картинки!");
        $this->model->userImage($image, "Картинка не загрузилась!");

        if(empty($this->model->getErrors())) {
            $sel = $this->model->getGroupId($group);//проверяем, еслть ли в таблице группа, которая была введена
            $gr = $this->db->fetch_assoc($sel);
            $groupid = $gr['groupId'];
            if(!$groupid) {//если есть, в group записываем значение уже существующей группы
                $new = $this->model->insertIntoGroup($group);
                $groupid = $this->db->getId();//id запроса
                $data[] = "Новая группа";
            } else {
                $data[] =  "Уже существующая группа";
            }

            $new = $this->model->insertInto($groupid, $login, $password, $email, $date, $image);//новая запись в consumer
            $id_query = $this->db->getId();//id запроса

            if($new) {
                $namepic = $this->model->nameImg($path, $image, $id_query, $ext);//новое название картинки
                $update = $this->model->update($namepic, $login);//меняем название картинки на новое
                $data[] =  "Успех";
            } else {
                $data[] =  "Ошибка, не все поля заполнены";
            }

        } else {
            foreach($this->model->getErrors() as $err) {
                $data[] =  "<br>".$err;
                $data[] =  "Найдена ошибка";
            }
        }
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}


UserView.php: 


<form id="feedback" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
<label><p>Login</p><input type="text" id="login" name="login"></label>
<label><p>Password</p><input type="password" id="password" name="password">     </label>
<label><p>Group</p><input type="text" id="group" name="group"></label>
<label><p>Email</p><input type="email" id="email" name="email"></label>
<label><p>Date</p><input type="text" id="date" name="date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"></label>
<label><p>Image</p><input type="file" id="picture" name="picture"></label>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="Добавить">
```

Подскажите, если кто знает в чем проблема, всем спасибо

Comment: аджакс в полном порядке, надо смотреть проблему в самом индексе

Comment: надо смотреть на код где прописан сам jquery

Comment: Есть несколько вопросов, это что за framework ? Просто странно видеть actionIndex  обрабатывающий POST да и еще таким способом, складывается впечатление что на echo json_encode($data); запрос может не оканчиваться, попробуй ради интереса после него exit() врубить

Comment: Собственно точно, ты задаешь view в конструкторе, видать механизм отрабатывает дальше и выводит твой вид сделай return вместо echo

Comment: @Orange_shadow, c exit() работает, все правильно

Comment: @Orange_shadow, но с return не работает

Comment: Ну exit тут не лучший вариант :) это я , для проверки ), смотри как это делать в framework, который ты используешь

Comment: @Orange_shadow, да это я просто недавно начал mvc изучать, вот и пытаюсь на нем что то сделать)

Comment: @myfavoritename попробуй сперва просто прочесть доку, даже не сильно вдаваясь в подробности, просто что б знать, что да как, а вот второй раз уже читай и кодь. :) так будет проще, потому что документация хоть и является руководством к действию, но не всегда пошаговым. Лучше сперва просто прочесть и составить общую картину.

Comment: @Orange_shadow спасибо вам большое) а можно будет уточнить у вас  еще пару нюансов по mvc? Только было бы неплохо в соц сети любой или в скайпе, чтоб здесь всё комментариями не забивать) если вы не против, конечно

Comment: @myfavoritename мой скайп, orange_adrenalin помогу, чем смогу